# Interpreting netlogit output

Tags: r, statistics

I have to compare the output of the following two models:

```
PTA.Logit.Ctrl <-glm(pta~ally+distance+ltrade+language+igo+affinity,
                 family=binomial(link="logit"),data=pta.ally.dyadic.1990.csv)
```

and

```
PTA.QAPX.Ctrl <-  netlogit(pta_network_1990,list(ally_network_1990,distance_1990,trade_1990, language_1990, igos_1990, affinity_1990), intercept=TRUE, mode="graph", diag=FALSE, nullhyp=c("qapx"), reps=100)
```

which look as follows:

[image]

and

[image]

Now the glm output is pretty straightforward i am however struggling with the net logit output especially with regards to significance scores. For the first model network data is used in dyadic form, for the second in matrix form. Any help with how to interpret the net logit output would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This question is really more appropriate for Cross Validated, since it is a statistics question, not a programming question. I will give an answer here and move it over if it gets migrated.

Comment: Oh yeah you are right, thanks for pointing that out and of course for your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike the glm model, which is parametric, the qap model is non-parametric, using a permutation-based approach, which is more appropriate for network data. You notice that the coefficients are similar (in fact, should be identical, since `netlogit` uses `glm` to estimate the model). However, the p-values and standard errors are where the models differ. The qap model permutes the row and columns of the model matrices (depending on the approach taken, which here is x permutations) and recalculates the coefficients and test statistics. It does this for the number of times indicated in `rep=n`. This creates a distribution, to which the initially estimated test statistics are compared. The three columns at the end (`Pr(<=b)`, etc) represent lower, upper, and two-tailed tests, respectively.

I will illustrate this with toy networks.

```
library(igraph); library(ggplot2)
x<-rgraph(25,2)
y.l<-x[1,,]*3
fit <- netlogit(y, x, reps=100, nullhyp = "qapx")
```

Here are the summary stats:

```
> summary(fit)

Network Logit Model

Coefficients:
            Estimate   Exp(b)    Pr(<=b) Pr(>=b) Pr(>=|b|)
(intercept)  0.1859224 1.2043289 1.00    1.00    1.00     
x1          -0.2377116 0.7884300 0.08    0.92    0.13     
x2          -0.2742033 0.7601775 0.03    0.97    0.08
```

You can see the distribution for each term in the model in the netlogit object with `fit$dist[,2]` for x1 and `fit$dist[,3]` for x2 and the test statistics using `fit$tstat[2]` and `fit$tstat[3]`

```
ggplot() + geom_density(aes(fit$dist[,2])) + geom_vline(aes(xintercept=fit$tstat[2]))
```

[image]

You can see that about 0.08 of the observations are less than or equal to the test statistic for x2, while 0.92 are greater than or equal to the test statistic.

We can see this numerically:

```
> mean(fit$dist[,2] >= fit$tstat[2])
[1] 0.92
> mean(fit$dist[,2] <= fit$tstat[2])
[1] 0.08
> mean(abs(fit$dist[,2]) >= abs(fit$tstat[2]))
[1] 0.13
```

We then interpret these p-values in standard way -- if there were no relationship between y and x1 (the null), then the probability of observing a test statistic as larger or larger is 0.92, etc. The key is that the distribution is not a parametic distribution, but based on permutations of the data.